# Comparing acidity of p-chloro benzoic acid and p-fluoro benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, halides

[image: o-chloro]

I am really confused about comparing the acidity of p-chloro benzoic acid and p-fluoro benzoic acid.

The question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76611/relative-acidity-of-halo-substituted-benzoic-acids-at-para-position) doesn't have a conclusion and the discussion [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-para-fluoro-benzoic-acid-is-less-acidic-than-para-chloro-benzoic-acid) is confusing.

---

**My Try:**

- -F and -Cl being +R groups create negative charge on o- and p- positions with respect to them.

  -F having greater +R effect tends to produce greater negative charge on the positions ortho and para to it

  -Cl having a greater +I effect tends to create greater amount of $\delta-$ charge than -F

  The acidity of the molecule depends on the negative charge on the starred carbon atom (greater negative charge$\implies$less acidic):

[image]

---

**My Confusions:**

Is inductive effect strong enough to act para to the specific group?

Which among -F and -Cl will produce greater cumulative negative charge on the starred carbon atom, and how?

---

**The answer given:**

p-chloro benzoic acid is more acidic than p-fluoro benzoic acid, contrary to the order existing between p-chloro benzoic acid, p-bromo benzoic acid and p-iodo benzoic acid